# Capture traffic from zend_http_client via fiddler

Tags: php, fiddler, zend-http-client

Im using zend_http_client and used code below to force traffic to fiddler :

```
        $Http_Client = new Zend_Http_Client($Address);

    $config = array(
                'adapter'       => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy',
                'proxy_host'    => '127.0.0.1',
                'proxy_port'    => 8888,
                'timeout'       => 60,
                'useragent'     => 'Test',
                'keepalive'     => true,
                'sslusecontext' => true

    );
    $Http_Client->setConfig($config);
```

when I run the program, I just get Http error 400 which means bad request.I searched a lot but found nothing helpful.In addition when I remove this config,everything works but fiddler does not capture any thing.
What can I do for this problem?

Comment: What is the FULL text of the HTTP/400 response, as seen in Fiddler's RAW response inspector tab?

Comment: HTTP/1.0 400 This buggy server did not return headers

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at www.target.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Comment: Finally I found this : Message: Unable to Connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:8888. Error #10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.   any help now?

Comment: It sounds like your HTTP request is malformed. Please send me (Help > Send Feedback) a SAZ file (File > Save Sessions to Archive ZIP) containing the traffic in question.

Comment: saz file here : http://www.4shared.com/file/TvTnrRp8/Request.html               code here : http://www.4shared.com/file/8BREU6tZ/code.html

Comment: The file you've sent includes 400kb of obfuscated JavaScript, which was likely returned by a SQUID proxy instance at "cache.ShabdizNet.com". Sending the same request from here doesn't return that result, although it looks like the correct URL has a "www." in front of the hostname.

Comment: That is my ISP name. I will solve the problem and will tell you where the problem was. I have to test my program through other proxies!